# VS 2015 Solution Makes DLL But Entry Point is Missing

Tags: c#, dll

VS 2015 Solution Makes DLL But Entry Point is Missing

Hi.  I have a "missing entry point" problem.  I have searched here in StackOverflow and found a LOT of hits, but they are for different environments, different versions of VS, or there is some other reason why their answers don't apply.  Or, in some cases, I tried implementing the solution given, but it didn't fix my problem.

I have created a simple Visual Studios Community 2015 Solution.  The goal of this dll is to provide a way for the caller to display information in a Windows MessageBox.

Here is the Solution.

```
using System.Windows.Forms;    
namespace IO_Routines
{
    public static class IO_Routines_Class
    {
        public static void Echo(int value1, ref int value2)
        {
            DialogResult result = MessageBox.Show("MADE IT!!!  Value1 = " + 
                value1.ToString() + ".",
                "debug", MessageBoxButtons.OK);

            if (result == DialogResult.OK)
                value2 = 1;
            else
                value2 = 2;
            MessageBox.Show("Value from previous MessageBox = " + 
                value2.ToString() + ".",
                "debug", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
            return;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is what I get when I build it:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: IO_Routines, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  IO_Routines -> F:\SBIR\VS2015\IO_Routines\IO_Routines\bin\Debug\IO_Routines.dll
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

And there is an IO_Routines.dll file.

But when I start Dependency Walker and open IO_Routines.dll, there should be an entry point for Echo.  There is not.

Why isn't there an entry point for Echo?  Have I missed a step?  Is there a missing argument for the declaration of Echo?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: An entry point for a program is not really the same thing as an invoked method on a dll. Is there some reason you are using dependencywalker instead of just referencing your IO_Routines and calling the Echo() method from a project? (you can also use ILSpy)

Comment: If you are using this in some other .Net project, add a reference. If you are trying to use this from C or C++, then you have more work to do to get this to work...

Comment: A C# assembly does *not* have entrypoints for its methods.  Nor could that work, only the jitter can ensure that the method gets translated to machine code and knows the address.  There are ways to get native entrypoints, C++/CLI is one way, Giesecke's Unmanaged Exports utility is another.

Comment: @StingyJack: Yes, the reason I'm not just referencing my IO_Routines is because I'm trying to set up a managed C# dll that I can call from an unmanaged dll. In the end, I need a way to display information that comes from a thread that is generated in the unmanaged dll. And the reason I'm using an unmanaged dll is because the thread has to run very, very fast, so I've written it in plain vanilla C.

Comment: @crashmstr: Yes, I do have more work to do. That's what I don't know, and what I'm asking for. Surely this isn't the first time this issue has come up.

Comment: @ColleenKobe the point was that you don't tell us why this is important (i.e. how it is being used), so we can't tell you how to "fix" it. See comment from Hans Passant how this is not an automatic thing and possible things to look into. COM (Component Object Model) may also be a way to do this.

Comment: @crashmstr: It is hard to know how much information to include in these posts. I've posted other questions with ALL the file listings and my goals but no one replies. So now I keep it focused and to a minimum and that's wrong too. This question just seemed like it should be a no-brainer--something people do every day--to someone who is more fluent in C# than I am, which is pretty much everyone.....Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: I dont know if just being written in vanilla C is going to make a program automatically faster than c#. There is a lot to do with developer skill that goes into making something faster or more performant. For your scenario, take a look at this link that gives a plain example of how to expose a .net assembly to other unmanaged callers. Com interop is not a trivial process and has pitfalls to consider, so be sure this is what you want instead of a pinvoke for msgbox. https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828736?wa=wsignin1.0

Comment: @StingyJack. Thank you for the suggestion about Com interop. I looked at the web page you provided and I see what you mean about it not being trivial. ... Re plain vanilla C vs C# and speed. Of course you're right about C not being automatically faster than C#; it depends on how the code is written.... I am still learning C# but I find I make assumptions about VS that aren't true. Like: I can call an "unmanaged" dll from VS, but VS does not provide the return courtesy of its dlls being easy to call.

Comment: Eh, the "return courtesy" is not so much a VS concern but one where MS is trying to move from COM+ (Com v2) to .NET (Com v3 - cant be COM3 due to port naming).